# How can I enable verbose output in apt?

Tags: debian, apt

I'm having a weird issue with apt were it hangs during `apt update`. I want to enable verbose output to see what exactly is causing this problem or at least where it occurs. The manpage for `apt-get` doesn't seem to contain anything related.

How can I enable verbose output for `apt`?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The `apt` tools provide a number of `Debug` configuration options, that you can either set persistently via a file in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d` or (probably more usefully) pass as a `-oDebug::` option on the command line.

The `Debug::pkgAcquire` group looks like the most relevant for the issues that you are describing. From `man apt.conf`:

```
  Debug::pkgAcquire::Worker
       Log all interactions with the sub-processes that actually perform
       downloads.
```

So for example you can try

```
sudo apt -oDebug::pkgAcquire::Worker=1 update
```

Comment: Use `man apt.conf` and search for `DEBUG` to get a list of these options.